# Microsoft Excel sheets become black

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I am working on excel 2016, after pressing some keys (I think CTRL and some key, I cant remember), Excel sheet suddenly becomes black, I tried to undo but I cannot. I closed and opened but problem still the same, no columns were showing. No hidden columns, no conditional formatting. Please suggest me a way to fix this problem.

[image: Black sheet excel attached below]

Comment: You will need to post your spreadsheet online if you would like us to have a look (OneDrive, Dropbox etc).

Comment: Can you type cells in Workbook? Did this problem appear in all Workbooks or specific Workbook?

Answer (score 0):

Try File>Account>Office Theme

[image]

You might have changed the theme to black, try changing to colorful.
Hope that helps.